# Keep getting empty notifications from PubSubHubBub

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, websub

I have successfully subscribed to my own dummy channel (for dev testing). My .net Socket listener receives a connection when I update, but it has nothing in common with the XML example provided by google.
It looks like this:

```
Client connected from 192.168.2.8:11000
Received:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: ##.##.##.##:11000
Link: <https://www.youtube.com/xml/feeds/videos.xml?channel_id=~~channelID~~>; rel=self, <http://pubsubhubbub.appspot.com/>; rel=hub
Content-Type: application/atom+xml
Cache-Control: no-cache,max-age=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
From: googlebot(at)googlebot.com
User-Agent: FeedFetcher-Google; (+http://www.google.com/feedfetcher.html)
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,br
```

I get something that looks like that every time a new video is added. No actual notifications. Am I supposed to use this as a hint to poll the videos on the channel, and find the new one? I thought you'd get some kind of XML bit.